# Energy and spacetime: a doubt on notation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In the reference $[1]$ I saw a very neat formula, given by:

$$ \mathcal{E} =: \int_{\Sigma} d^{3}x T_{00} = \frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_{\Sigma} d^{3}x G_{00}.   \tag{1}$$

The author stated that this is the "energy in a space-time". At first glance nothing is bothering me at all, though it seems a little bit hand-waving notation (and that's the reason for this question). Nevertheless, is just Einstein Field Equations so it must be physically correct.

> My doubt is: **the $d^{3}x$ increments are just spatial volume or must to be a $d^{4}x$ instead? Or, in other words, the equation $(1)$ shouldn't be written as**
>
> $$\mathcal{E} =: \frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_{\Sigma} d^{4}x G_{00} =$$ $$= \frac{1}{8\pi G}\Bigg[\int^{x^{3}_{2}}_{x^{3}_{1}} \int^{h_{2}(x^{3})}_{h_{1}(x^{3})} \int^{g_{2}(x^{3},x^{2})}_{g_{1}(x^{3},x^{2})} \int^{q_{2}(x^{3},x^{2},x^{1})}_{q_{1}(x^{3},x^{2},x^{1})} G_{00}\sqrt{-g}dx^{0}dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3}\Bigg] \tag{2}$$
>
> **in order to perform the explicit calculation (given a $G_{00}$ of course)?**

$$ * * * $$

$[1]$ LÜST.D; VLEESHOUWERS.W; *Black Hole Information and Thermodynamics*. page 28.

Comment: I think $\Sigma$ is a Cauchy surface of the spacetime of consideration, this is roughly spoken a maximal spacelike surface. For example $\Sigma$ could be an instantaneous surface of an observer for a given time, if this is admitted by the spacetime. But it is just a feeling. However, note that energy is a quantitiy typically defined for an instant of time. Thus, it makes sense to me to define it for a Cauchy surface.

Comment: I see, I think you're totally right. On the other hand I appreciate a explicit formula on how to calculate the integral $(1)$. The invariant term $\sqrt{-g}$ confuses me here.

Answer (score 2):

So in order to define an energy in any spacetime it must be *stationary*. This automatically means that none of the metric components (and consequently none of the stress tensor components) depend on time. The hypersurface $\Sigma$ that we are integrating on in this notation is also a 3-dimensional spatial surface.

The above notation hence refers to integration over a spatial hypersurface of a scalar quantity $T_{00}$ which, in general, only depends on three spatial coordinates.